# Где можно поработать за опыт удаленно(front-end)?

Tags: вёрстка, веб-программирование, frontend

**Предисловие:** Здравствуйте, месяц назад я начал изучать Web-разработку, уволился с предыдущего места работы, сделал себе финансовую подушку на 4 месяца + помощь родителей. На обучение я трачу 6-8ч в день, в данный момент неплохо освоил HTML и CSS, недавно принялся за изучение JS. Сверстал несколько статичных макетов, сейчас приступаю к адаптивной верстке с использованием методологии БЭМ и препроцессора Less(осваиваю в процессе). 
Сразу оговорюсь, что я живу в городе с населением в 20к, и здесь нету не одной конторы по Web-разработке, а с некоторых пор я переехал за город, в частный дом. До ближайшего города с вакансиями 2-3 часа езды(водительских прав у меня нету). 
После лета я собираюсь переехать в СПБ и хотелось бы к тому времени набраться опыта разработки.

**О себе**: 20 лет, горят глаза, есть цель.

**Суть вопроса:** Существует ли ресурс где, можно получить работу за опыт? Или где люди могут мне передавать часть своей работы, я буду её выполнять, отдавать на проверку и она в дальнейшем будет использоваться в реальном проекте, хотелось бы делать что-то, что будет использоваться людьми и приносить какую-то пользу, а так же получить опыт работы в команде. Я понимаю что удаленно работать в команде для новичка не самая лучшая затея, но на данный момент у меня нету выхода.

Так же хотелось хотелось бы получить совет по вектору обучения, в данный момент у меня он таков: HTML => CSS => JS => jQuery => 1 из серверных языков, для того, чтобы понимать что вообще происходит на той стороне(присматриваюсь к RoR) => ???

**Спасибо!**

Comment: Почти уверен, что вопрос заминусуют, т. к. по факту это много вопросов в одном, в вопросе больше контекста чем требуется, а суть вопроса оффтопик для сайта. Но ситуация, должен отметить, грустная. Для начала стоит зафиксировать собственные достижения в демках, опубликовать их на гитхабе (у них есть [Pages](https://pages.github.com/), а `git` всё равно стоит владеть). Это уже займёт какое-то время и хотя бы даст основания для разговора с кем-нибудь.